# ¿Cómo puedo comprobar que un String contiene ciertos caracteres?

Tags: python

Tengo una duda que no se como explicarla bien ni tampoco supe como redactar bien la pregunta, pero creo que con el código se puede ver mi atención.

**La premisa es "si una clave tiene una consonante oclusiva entonces es aceptada"**.

```
data=["zzk","bro","asdf","contrasena","end"]
consonantes_oclusiva = ["p","t","k","b","d","g"]

for clave in data:
    if clave == "end":
        break
    for caracter in clave:
        ######aqui abajo es#####
        if caracter == "p" or caracter == "t" or caracter == "k" or caracter == "b" or caracter == "d" or caracter =="g":
            print("La clave {} es valida".format(clave))
```

¿Hay algún método de strings o listas que me permita saber si algún carácter de la lista "consonantes_oclusiva" esta dentro de una clave(elemento de data) mas rápidamente? algo así como el método para strings  "string.count("caracter")"?

¿Debería tener la variable de consonantes como string en vez de lista?

espero se halla entendido el problema :)

Comment: al hacer un for estas recorriendo caracter a caracter por lo tanto con solo "if caracter in consonates_oclusiva:" , se fija si está en la lista, también puede ser una cadena o tupla es indistinto

Comment: @tincopasan muchas gracias, lo estaba haciendo al revés como lo dijiste tu xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La primera mejora que puedes hacer es utilizar `in` en el if.

```
if caracter in consonantes_oclusiva:
```

Y eso dará `true` si el carácter está dentro de la lista.

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es usar `set` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)
La teoría de conjuntos (set) es bastante divertida pero para el caso lo que nos importa saber es que para dos listas (N y M) podemos unirlas en un nuevo set (union `N | M`), sacar la lista de los items que existen en ambos sets (intersection `N & M`) o sacar la lista de los que solo existen en uno de los dos sets (difference `N - M`) entre otras operaciones.

En este caso nos interesa la intersección, y aquí un ejemplo:

```
N = {'z', 'z', 'k'}
M = {'p', 't', 'k', 'b', 'd', 'g'}

N & M = {'k'}
```

Esto se traduce a `N` contiene una de las letras en `M`

Y el código sería el siguiente

```
data=["zzk","bro","asdf","contrasena","end"]
consonantes_oclusiva = set(["p","t","k","b","d","g"])

for clave in data:
    if clave == "end":
        break

    # o: if set(clave) & consonantes_oclusiva:
    if set(clave).intersection(consonantes_oclusiva):
        print("La clave {} es valida".format(clave))
```

Nótese que hemos hecho de `consonantes_oclusiva` un `set`. Y que convertimos `clave` ("zzk") en un `set` y python automáticamente lo convierte a `set("z", "z", "k")`.

Comment: Buena respuesta! Detalle de sintaxis, puedes poner `set(clave) & consonantes_oclusiva`